# How to place the div elements inline?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place these two divs `inline`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="thisFlak">
</div>

<div class="thisFlakNotes">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thisFlak{
  width: 603px;
  height: 253px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.thisFlakNotes{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

I cannot mess with ".thisFlak" to much because it hold alot of other stuff.

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/xwzcbn6w/

Comment: you can either float them or use `display:inline-block`, if you use the latter, beware of the additional space it may add between the blocks

Comment: You can use `float:left` also. There are lots of ways of doing it. Just depends on the result you are looking for. You can use `flex` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xwzcbn6w/4/)

CSS

```
.thisFlak {
  width: 603px;
  height: 253px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  /* to make it inline */
  display: inline-block; 
  /* aligning vertically you can make it top / bottom / baseline */
  vertical-align: middle
}

.thisFlakNotes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  /* to make it inline */
  display: inline-block;
  /* aligning vertically you can make it top / bottom / baseline */ 
  vertical-align: middle 
}
```

Comment: Extra plus for the `vertical-align` tip!

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline-block;` will allow you to keep the dimensions and put your divs on the same line.  It will treat the divs like words in a sentence though so you will need to comment out any space between them and as they are different heights, you will need to add vertical alignment:

```css
.thisFlak{
   vertical-align:top;
    width: 603px;
    height: 253px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.thisFlakNotes{
   vertical-align:top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="thisFlak">
</div><!-- comment out this space

--><div class="thisFlakNotes">
</div>
```

**Update**

Also if you don't want the boxes to wrap when the page is too small for them to fit on one line, you will need to add `white-space:nowrap` to the parent (or make sure the width of the parent is wider than the two children)

Answer (score 1):

By Adding `float:left / display:inline` to both classes you can achieve it.

Here is the updated fiddle link[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwzcbn6w/7/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Your code:

```
.thisFlak{
  width: 603px;
  height: 253px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thisFlakNotes{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

float...
https://jsfiddle.net/maky/xwzcbn6w/2/

```
.thisFlak {
  width: 603px;
  height: 253px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.thisFlakNotes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I dont know why, but `float left`did not work me as the elements end up intop of eachother.

Answer (score 0):

just put display : inline-block or float : left to each div

```
.thisFlak{
  width: 603px;
  height: 253px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  float : left;
  display : inline-block;
}
.thisFlakNotes{
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
 float : left;
 display : inline-block;
}
```